# Estimation of Survival Probability

Tags: probability

I am reading a book which gives the way to calculate the Survival and fault probabilities as follows. Below table is given an reference -

```
+------+-------------+----------------+
| Year | Death Prob. | Survival Prob. |
+------+-------------+----------------+
|    1 |        0.02 |           0.98 |
|    2 |      0.0196 |         0.9604 |
|    3 |      0.0192 |         0.9412 |
|    4 |      0.0188 |         0.9224 |
|    5 |      0.0184 |         0.9039 |
+------+-------------+----------------+
```

The calculation of the elements are mentioned as below -

Suppose that the probability of an object is damaged during a year conditional
on no earlier damage is 2%. The table shows survival probabilities and unconditional
probabilities of being damaged for each of the 5 years. The probability that an object will get damaged during the first year is 0.02 and the probability that it will survive until the end of the first year is 0.98. The probability of being damaged during the second year is `0:02 *  0:98 = 0:0196` and the probability of survival until the end of the second year is `0:98* 0:98 = 0:9604`.

I failed to understand the reasoning for the calculation that probability of being damaged during the second year is `0:02 *  0:98 = 0:0196`.

Assuming I am given the column for the total Survival probability (the last column), how should I get the Death Probability column except the trivial first case?

Any insight is very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $N$ be the random variable denoting the year of death, and for $n = 1,2, \ldots$ we denote
$$D_n = \mathbf P[N = n], \qquad S_n = \mathbf P[N > n]$$
respectively the probability of death in year n (the left hand column in your table), and the probability of survival beyond the $n$-th year (the right hand column).

The probability you have been given is the probability of death in a given year, **conditioned** on having survived to the previous year. I.e. the condition

$$ \mathbf P[N = n + 1 | N > n] = 0.02 = \rho.$$

In the first year we have:
$$D_1 = \rho, \qquad S_1 = (1 - \rho).$$

For the second year we make use of the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability):

$$
\begin{align}
D_2 & = \mathbf P[N = 2 | N = 1 ] \mathbf P[N = 1] +
 \mathbf P[N = 2 | N > 1 ]\mathbf P[N > 1] \\
& = \big( 0 \times D_1 \big) + \mathbf P[N = 2 | N > 1 ]S_1 \\
& = 0 + \rho S_1 \\
& = \rho \times (1 - \rho).
\end{align}
$$
The survival probability is then

$$
\begin{align}
S_2 & = S_1 - D_2\\
& = (1-\rho) - (1-\rho)\rho \\
& = (1- \rho)^2
\end{align}
$$

---

More generally you can derive the probabilities for the higher terms by induction.

We suppose that $D_n, \, S_n$ follow the equations

$$D_n = \rho(1-\rho)^{n-1}\, \qquad S_n = (1- \rho)^n$$

then the same approach as for the case $n = 2$ can be applied
$$
\begin{align}
D_{n+1} & = \mathbf P[N = n+1 | N \leq n] \mathbf P[N \leq n ] + \mathbf P[N = n +1 | N > n ] \mathbf P[N > n ] \\
& = \mathbf P[N = n +1 | N > n ] \mathbf P[N > n ]  \\
& = \rho S_n
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
S_{n+1} & = S_n - D_{n+1} \\
& = S_n - \rho S_n \\
& = (1 - \rho)S_n
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Should not `probability of DEFAULTING the next year, conditioned on having survived to now` is $\rho$?

Comment: So assuming you are equating defaulting = death, then this is the conditional probability that I use above: $\mathbf P[N = n+1 | N > n] = \rho$, with the interpretation that $n+1$ as next year, and $n$ is now.

Comment: Thanks, That I understand. However in your original answer above you said `The probability you have been given is the probability of surviving the next year`. I am asking if the word `surviving ` is correct? Or it would be `death/defaulting`

Comment: Got it - yes, that could be worded more clearly : I'll update.

Comment: Apologies to revisit this old topic today. However I think I failed to convince myself on the expression for the first year i.e. $D_1=\rho$ and $S_1=1-\rho$, given that $\rho$ is conditional probability of default in 2nd year assuming it survived 1st year. Could you please help to get the intuition of this? Or, it is just hard-coded assumption?